# Pausing app to display message for one second before dismissing a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a simple timer that on completion shows the message "Rest Time Complete" I want that message to stay on the screen for one second, then dismiss a view. I've tried a few things that I'll detail below, but I can never get the message to display, pause, then dismiss the view. The timer pauses on the last number in the timer, then the message always appears as the view is being dismissed. Here is my code:

```
- (void)restTimerComplete
{
    self.restTimeLabel.text = @"Rest Period Complete!";
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    [self hideRestTimerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I've also tried using the simple `sleep(1)`, but that has the same end result.

Comment: **Never** sleep on the main thread, ever.

Comment: What is your recommendation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `dispatch_after`:

```
- (void)restTimerComplete {
    self.restTimeLabel.text = @"Rest Period Complete!";
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideRestTimerAnimated:YES];
    });

}
```